# How to make a mask div over the fullscreen except a sibling div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a `div` works as a mask to be placed over the full window. Its opacity is 0.5, background color is `lightgray`. But there is one `div` in the screen should not be impacted by the mask div. I try to set its `z-index` to be higher than the mask but it doesn't work. The code is below:

```css
.parent {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.sub1 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1;
}

.mask {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: lightgray;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
    <div class="parent">
      
      <div class="sub1">
        hello
      </div>
      
      <div class="mask">
      </div>
    </div>
```

as you can see, I want the `sub1` div on top of the `mask` but it doesn't. It is still show as 0.5 `opacity`.

Full code can also be run from https://codepen.io/zhaoyi0113/pen/vzERYY.

Comment: `z-index` only works on elements that have a position of `absolute`, `relative`, or `fixed`.  add `position:relative` to `sub1`

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a `position` property to `.sub1` otherwise the `z-index` won't work

> The z-index CSS property specifies the z-order of a **positioned** element
>   <sub>[z-index | MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index)</sub>

I recommend `position: relative;` since that won't screw with your document flow.

```
.sub1 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1;
  position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`calc()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) and set height of `mask` minus height of `sub` i.e. `100px` and also remove `position: fixed` from `mask` css. So below will be CSS for `mask`:

```
.mask {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: lightgray;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Below is working **demo**:

```css
.parent {
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.sub1 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 10;
  opacity: 1;
}

.mask {
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: -webkit-calc(100% - 100px);
  height: -moz-calc(100% - 100px);
  height: calc(100% - 100px);
  opacity: 0.5;
  background-color: lightgray;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  
  <div class="sub1">
    hello
  </div>
  
  <div class="mask">
  </div>
</div>
```

Working Codepen [**here**](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PdwRWb).